# Adding bootstrap modal in angular 4

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm adding a basic modal in Angular 4. The issue it's that it looks like the modal it's appearing in the backdrop of the page.

I have a profile.component.ts. Basically i have:

```
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; 
constructor(private modalService: NgbModal){}

open(){
      this.modalService.open('Hello there');
  }
```

In profile.component.html i have a button calling the open() function. When clicking at the button, the only thing that occurs it's the scroll bar appearing and disappearing.

I'm guessing that something is missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added some content? https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Comment: Yes, i tried with that. And the same. So i tried to take an easy way, at least for testing if something pops. I'm following this simple plunker example, http://plnkr.co/edit/5qq04Q4HFLOe9tsyeMMI?p=preview @JonathanDion

Comment: Maybe it's a CSS issue. Did you add the CSS file too?

Comment: yes i have the bootstrap cdn files added

Comment: Can you put all your code in a sandbox? Like plunker. I will take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `open()` and just sending the string will not work. `you should send Id instead`.

You can follow this example and it will work perfectly fine.

> **Code.ts**

```
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; 
constructor(private modalService: NgbModal){}

open(){
      this.modalService.open(sayHello);
  }

private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
    return 'by pressing ESC';
} else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
    return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
} else {
    return `with: ${reason}`;
}
}
```

> **Code.html**

```
<ng-template ngbModalContainer></ng-template>
<ng-template #sayHello let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-header ">
        <h6 class="modal-title text-uppercase ">Headding</h6>
        <button type="button " class="close " aria-label="Close " (click)="d( 'Cross click') ">
      <span aria-hidden="true ">&times;</span>
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-header ">
       HELLO :)
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn " (click)="d( 'Cross click') ">Close</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

and don't forget to import

`import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';` in your `app.module.ts`

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';    
imports: [ NgbModule.forRoot(),
    ...
    ...
    ]
```

I think this should help.

Comment: can you be more specific about your question @sree

Comment: I am new to Angular 4 and i don't know in which file we need to keep the code of code.html file from above

Comment: Whichever component you need your model to appear you can place the code there.